# How to get iphone 4 on the simulator device menu

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I just downloaded the latest SDK from apple, and installed without a problem, but I still don't have iPhone 4 in the device menu on the simulator. The simulator says it is version 4.2 (235).  Anyone have any clues about this?

Comment: I assume you're looking for specifically version 4.0, rather than 4.2?

Comment: I don't think there is an iPhone 4.2 Cody.  The 4.2 I mention in the question is the simulator version, not an iPhone version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out that Hardware->Device->iPhone (Retina) is actually iPhone 4.  I had thought it wasn't, in part because the reported screen resolution was 320x480.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772647/simulator-iphone-retina-has-wrong-screen-resolution) for a thorough discussion about this.  Aditya is wrong when he says "the iPhone 4 simulator is launched by default".  This actually depends on your build settings, targeted device family.

Answer (score 0):

When you download the latest Xcode,and run your program in simluator,the iPhone 4 simulator is launched by default,so you don't have to worry about that.

Cheers